# How to get Youtube Editor spotlight annotations to show up once uploaded on Vimeo

Tags: editing

I have added spotlight annotations to a Youtube video by using Youtube editor. I tried uploading it to Vimeo and the spotlights disappeared. Can someone please tell me how to get the annotations to show up in Vimeo after being made in Youtube? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Vimeo doesn't support such a feature like the YouTube annotations.
You also can't export your YouTube annotations, YouTube doesn't offer any method for that.